# Preserve checkbox ribbon state on opening workbook

Tags: excel, vba, ribbon

I created a tab "MYTAB" in the ribbon with 2 checkboxes to hide and show columns.
I need to retain the checkboxes state when the workbook is reopened.

**CustomUi code:**

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="rxIRibbonUI_onLoad">
<ribbon>
    <tabs>
        <tab id="myTab" label="MYTAB">
            <group id="Group1" label="Hide Columns">
                <checkBox 
                    id="chkClass12"
                    label=" Class12"
                    getPressed="rxClass_getPressed"
                    onAction="rxClass_onAction"/>
                <checkBox 
                    id="chkClass34"
                    label="Class34"
                    getPressed="rxClass_getPressed"
                   onAction="rxClass_onAction"/>
            </group>
        </tab>
    </tabs>
</ribbon>
```

**Module code:**

```
Public b_chkClass12 As Boolean
Public b_chkClass34 As Boolean
Public MyRibbon As IRibbonUI

Sub rxIRibbonUI_onLoad(ribbon As IRibbonUI)
    Set MyRibbon = ribbon
End Sub

Public Sub rxClass_getPressed(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef returnedVal)
    Select Case control.ID
        Case "b_chkClass12":
            returnedVal = b_chkClass12

        Case "b_chkClass34":
            returnedVal = b_chkClass34
    End Select
End Sub

Public Sub rxClass_onAction(control As IRibbonControl, pressed As Boolean)
    Select Case control.ID
        Case "chkClass12":
            b_chkClass12 = pressed
            Worksheets("Sheet1").[oClass12].Value = pressed
            Call ShowHideColumns("Class12")

        Case "chkClass34":
            b_chkClass34 = pressed
            Worksheets("Sheet1").[oClass34].Value = pressed
            Call ShowHideColumns("Class34")
    End Select
End Sub

Sub ShowHideColumns(nRange As String)
    Range(nRange).EntireColumn.Hidden = Not Range(nRange).EntireColumn.Hidden
End Sub
```

**ThisWorkbook code:**

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    With Worksheets("Sheet1").[oClass12]
        If .Value = True Then
            b_chkClass12 = True
        Else
            b_chkClass12 = False
        End If
    End With

    With Worksheets("Sheet1").[oClass34]
        If .Value = True Then
            b_chkClass34 = True
        Else
            b_chkClass34 = False
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

**Sheet that is keeping the values**

[image]

**Name Manager**´

[image]

Regards,
Elio Fernandes

Comment: One way would be to store the values in a hidden worksheet, but I recall some guy saving them in an Excel `Name` which really is neat: http://drvignesh.blogspot.co.nz/2015/07/vba-ribbon-ui-persistent-state.html

Comment: Ambie, I am doing that. But when the workbook opens the checkboxes are empty. I think that something is missing on  Workbook_Open procedure.

Comment: I believe they retain their default state on opening until you `invalidate` the ribbon.

Comment: Tell me how and where should I do it

Comment: It's in the link of my first comment.

Comment: Ambie I've read I see your file and for me its not very intuitive. If you look at my code, can you tell me what I need to change?